# Pet Database Design

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

Let me rephrase my question since I don't think I accurately described it.

I'm trying to determine the best way to link pet entries to their appropriate breed table based on the value in their species field. Pets can have more than one breed if they are a mix.  Would a setup like this be efficient? Or is there a better way to do this.  Should I separate species into a separate table as well?

Would this complicate joining results since I have to determine the value of species before knowing what breed table to join with?

Table Pets:

```
id | name  | species
1  | Spot  | Dog
2  | Kitty | Cat
3  | Chip  | Dog
4  | Sunny | Horse
```

Table Dog Breeds:

```
id | breed
1  | German Shepherd
2  | Golden Retreiver
3  | Black Lab
4  | Boxer
```

Table Cat Breeds:

```
id | breed
1  | Tabby
2  | Persian
3  | British Shorthair
4  | Ragdoll
```

Table pet_dog_breed

```
pet_id | dog_breed_id
1      | 2
1      | 4
```

Table pet_cat_breed

```
pet_id | cat_breed_id
2      | 1
```

Thanks!

Comment: Not "pivot table", rather "many:many mapping table".  Yes.  And here are some tips:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

Answer (score 0):

Table Pets:

`id | name 
1  | Spot 
2  | Kitty
3  | Chip 
4  | Sunny`

Table Breeds:

`id | breed            | species
1  | German Shepherd  | Dog
2  | Golden Retreiver | Cat
3  | Black Lab        | Dog
4  | Boxer            | Cat`

Table pet_breed

`pet_id | breed_id
1      | 2
1      | 4`

I would like to layout the database in this shape